# Smallest proposition given a state $\psi$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

Today, in my lecture the following was mentioned:

> Given a state $| \psi \rangle$ in a Hilbert Space $H$, the smallest proposition which is true given this state is given by the projection operator $| \psi \rangle \langle \psi |$, which is the smallest projection operator that projects onto the one-dimensional subspace $| \psi \rangle$.

There are few things I don't understand here. What is meant by smallest projection operator? Also why is the outer product $| \psi \rangle \langle \psi |$ the smallest?

Comment: Not sure, but do you think this has something to do with this - $$\Sigma _n | \psi \rangle \langle \psi | =1 $$

(Assuming a discrete basis set)

Comment: @Mitchell my guess here would be that the projection operators can be given an "ordering" because there is bijective correspondence between projections in Hilbert space and closed subspaces. So if $P_1 \lt P_2$ then the range of $P_1$ is smaller than $P_2$. However, I'm not quite sure why the projection operator above is the smallest.

Comment: The statement is pointless. ".. projects onto the one-dimensional subspace.. " means that the range of the projection $P$ is the span of $\psi$. But the orthogonal projection onto a subspace is unique, so there is nothing to compare with. It could make sense if we think about non-orthogonal projections but I am not aware of any partial order there besides the one induced by inclusion (the operators are not Hermitian anymore).

Comment: @MarkusHeinrich I think in the context of the statement projections are assumed to be orthogonal and I think you are correct (not 100% sure) that the ordering is given by construction of the lattice of projections as illustrated here  https://planetmath.org/latticeofprojections

Comment: What was the context of this statement?  In other words, what was the main topic of the lecture?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert the lecture concerned propositions and quantum logic. Here by propositions were meant to be statement of the form "A lies in some interval of reals given some state", which would be represtented by  projection operators (more specifically by spectral projections of the self-adjoint operator that represents the physical quantity $A$

Comment: I am not very familiar with quantum logic, but could it be that the statement was really meant to say: Among all (orthogonal) projections $P$ which contain $\psi$ in its range, $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ is the smallest. This would also fit nicely to the psd ordering that SolubleFish mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

This terminology is not familiar to me, but I can think of only one possibility :

For Hermitian operators, there is a notion of positivity (and therefore an order). In this case we would say that a hermitian projector $P$ is smaller than another $Q$ if :
$$\forall |\varphi\rangle, \langle \varphi|P|\varphi\rangle\leq \langle \varphi|Q|\varphi\rangle$$
We see that this is equivalent to the range of $P$ being included in that of $Q$. As any closed subspace containing $|\psi\rangle$ will contain the range of $P$, we see that $P$ is the smallest orthogonal projector with $P|\psi\rangle = |\psi\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks, your notion of ordering makes perfect sense to me. However, I don't quite get why is $|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$ the smallest?

Comment: @mathripper it is certainly the smallest orthogonal projection $P$ for which $P|\psi\rangle = |\psi\rangle$. But this is not the original statement (see my comment above).